# Memory mapped files that are contiguous on disk

Tags: c#, .net, memory, io, disk-io

I've read quite a few SO posts and general articles on trying to allocate over 1GB of memory so before getting shot down like the others here is some context.

This app will run as a kiosk with a dedicated machine running no unnecessary processes.

My app acquires images from a high-speed camera with a rolling shutter at a rate of 120 frames per second at a resolution of 1920 x 1080 with a bit depth of 24. The app needs to write every single frame to disk for post-processing. The current problem I am facing is that the Disk I/O won't keep up with the capture rate even though it is limited to 120 frames per second. The Disk I/O bandwidth needed is around 750MBps!

The total length of the recording needs to be at least 10 seconds (7.5GB) in raw form. Performing any on-the-fly transcoding or compression brings the frame-rate down to utterly unacceptable levels.

To work around this, I have tried the following:

- Compromising on quality by reducing the bit-depth at hardware-level to 16 which is still around 500MBps.
- Disabled all image encoding and writing raw camera data to disk. This has saved some processing time.
- Creating a single 10GB file on disk and doing a sequential write-through as frames come in. This has helped most so far. All dev and production systems have a 100GB dedicated drive for this application.
- Using Contig.exe from Sysinternals to defragment the file. This has had astonishing gains on non-SSD drives.

Out of options to explore here. I am not familiar with memory-mapped files and when trying to create them, I get an IOException saying `Not enough storage is available to process this command.`.

```
using (var file = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(@"D:\Temp.VideoCache", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, "MyMapName", int.MaxValue, MemoryMappedFileAccess.CopyOnWrite))
{
    ...
}
```

The large file I currently use requires either sequential write-though or sequential read access. Any pointers would be appreciated.

I could even force the overall recording size down to 1.8GB if only there was a way to allocate that much RAM. Once again, this will run on a dedicated with 8GB available memory and 100GB free space. However, not all production systems will have SSD drives.

Comment: Clearly the production system needs either a disk that can handle the throughput or enough memory to hold the overflow in memory while waiting for the disk to handle the load? Isn't that basically all there is to it? Unless you write your own file system or talk natively to NTFS or the specific file system there is no easy way to guarantee a continous file.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You certainly can allocate that much (1.8GB) of RAM. 64bit process and Win32 allocation functions (on a machine with sufficient RAM). But in the end you need a disk system with sufficient performance.

Comment: And also remember with memory mapped files you do not need to map file whole file into the process's memory space at the same time.

Comment: I can easily execute the code posted here on my own disks, creating a 2GB file. Do you have enough free space on disk?

Comment: @lasse Perhaps he is trying to run it at 32 bits... on 32 bits a 1gb contiguous memory block isn't guaranteed to be present.

Comment: That's a point I missed out on. Yes my process is 32 bit and due to third-party libraries we are using, we cannot switch to 64 bit at the moment.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: The available memory and disk space is sufficient. It is the throughput that causes capture buffers to overrun and cause outofmemory exceptions. We do not have the option of dropping frames here. The recording only needs to last for 10 seconds.

Comment: @RaheelKhan Even SSD disks can do up to 500-600mb/s, so a single SSD disk wouldn't be enough... On a machine with 7.5gb of ram something could be doable (your 32 bits process "transmits" to another 64 bits process the raw data... The big block of memory is allocated by the 64 bits process).

Comment: To give some numbers, taking for good the 500mb/s of an SSD, in 10 seconds you would be able to save 5gb of the file, and 2.5gb would still be in memory... But this if everything goes smoothly and the SSD isn't slowed by anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

32 bit processes on a 64 bit system can allocate 4 GB of RAM, so it should be possible to get 1.8 GB of RAM for storing the video, but of course you need to consider loaded DLLs and a buffer until the video is compressed.

Other than that, you could use a RAMDisk, e.g. from [DataRam](http://memory.dataram.com/products-and-services/software/ramdisk). You just need to find a balance between how much memory the application needs and how much memory you can grant the disk. IMHO a 5 GB / 3 GB setting could work well: 1 GB for the OS, 4 GB for your application and 3 GB for the file.

Don't forget to copy the file from the RAM disk to HDD if you want it persistent.

Comment: Thank you Thomas. RAMDisk looks very promising. I'll try it our and revert back. As for your first point, I have found no way to allocate over 600MB of RAM programatically. Even xanatos' answer seems to indicate that MM files will nto speed up sequential write-though scenarios. If there are unmanaged calls I could use to acquire more memory that would be great. The app is 32-bit and will ALWAYS run on 64-bit OSes.

Comment: It is possible that you can only get 600 MB of contiguous RAM due to memory fragmentation. Try allocating 100 MB several times. I guess you can allocate memory for single frames (n*8MB) and don't need a single large block (1800 MB).

Answer (score 1):

Commodity hardware is cheap for a reason.  You need faster hardware.

Buy a faster disk **system**.  A good RAID controller and four SSDs.  Put the drives into a RAID 1+0 configuration and be done with this problem.

How much money is your company planning on spending developing and testing software to push cheap hardware past its limitations?  And even if you can get it to work fast enough, how much do they plan on spending to maintain that software?

Answer (score 1):

1. Memory mapped files don't speed-up very much writing to a file...
2. If you have a big file, you normally don't try to map it entirely in RAM... you map a "window" of it, then "move" the window (in C#/Windows API you create a "view" of the file starting at any one location and with a certain size)

Example of code: (here the window is 1mb big... bigger windows are possible... at 32 bits it should be possible to allocate a 64 or 128mb window without any problem)

```
const string fileName = "Test.bin";
const long fileSize = 1024L * 1024 * 16;
const long windowSize = 1024 * 1024;

if (!File.Exists(fileName)) {
    using (var file = File.Create(fileName)) {
        file.SetLength(fileSize);
    }
}

long realFileSize = new FileInfo(fileName).Length;

if (realFileSize < fileSize) {
    using (var file = File.Create(fileName)) {
        file.SetLength(fileSize);
    }
}

using (var mm = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(fileName, FileMode.Open)) {
    long start = 0;

    while (true) {
        long size = Math.Min(fileSize - start, windowSize);

        if (size <= 0) {
            break;
        }

        using (var acc = mm.CreateViewAccessor(start, size)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                // It is probably faster if you write the file with
                // acc.WriteArray()
                acc.Write(i, (byte)i);
            }
        }

        start += windowSize;
    }
}
```

Note that here I'm writing code that will write a fixed pre-known number of bytes (`fileSize`)... Your code should be different (because you can't pre-know the "exact" `fileSize`). Still remember: **Memory mapped files don't speed-up very much writing to a file**.

Comment: Thank you. Your code sample gives a great view for getting started with MM files. I'm still trying to understand how I could optimize them for sequential write-throughs of about 500 MBps. I have at least 8GB of available memory and do not mind if it remains used up for the 10 seconds of recording. And yes, I do know the expected file size in advance (5GB for 10 seconds) if that helps optimize RAM utilization.

Comment: I don't know if I'm thinking about this wrong but ideally, memory usage should be allowed to increase while recording data is pushed in and the MM file is trying to persist as fast as it can.